# tar command to extract archive with colon in the name

Tags: regex, tar

I try `tar -zxvf plugin\:xyz.tgz` and received the error:

```
rsh: Could not resolve hostname plugin: Name or service not known
tar: plugin\:thold-latest.tgz: Cannot open: Input/output error
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
mv plugin\:xyz.tgz plugin-xyz.tgz
tar xvfp plugin-xyz.tgz
```

The name of the archive itself is not really that critical, and the files will extract to the same locations regardless of the archive name.

Answer (score 31):

Try `--force-local` option:

```
tar -zxvf plugin:xyz.tgz --force-local
```

From info pages

> If you need to use a file whose name includes a colon, then the remote tape drive behavior can be inhibited by using the `--force-local' option.

Answer (score 9):

the answer by @csg is spot on.

Another alternative, however, is specifying a **path** to the archive instead of its **filename**. This can either be an absolute path, or more simply a path relative to the current directory:

```
tar -zxvf ./plugin:xyz.tgz
```

this will force tar to interpret the name as a local file.

Comment: Given how many fewer keystrokes `./` is compared to `--force-local` (not to mention it's probably easier to remember), I'm astonished this isn't upvoted more than it is...

Answer (score 1):

Use the absolute path of tar.

Like this:

> /usr/bin/tar -xf plugin:thold-latest.tgz

The part before the ":" is interpreted as a host name, the part after would be a file. Tt tries to execute [remsh](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds4/rsh.htm). But with the absolute path of tar, it won't. Also, if you don't know where tar is on your system, run:

> whereis tar

Comment: Hi emb1995,
I've already tried your command. It was unsuccessful.
Tar keep interpreting ":" as the remote hostname.
I had to rename to file and extract it.

Comment: @Dzung Try it without the slash after "plugin". Is the slash part of the actual file name?

Answer (score 0):

Try Bandit's suggestion of quotes around the filename tar zxvf "blah:23.tar.gz"

Last resort, rename the file at the command line or through an SFTP/SCP application like WinSCP or FileZilla.. You could do this on your local machine and re-upload the renamed file or just login with WinSCP/FileZilla and right-click the file on the remote side and select rename.